# TcpListener used in Timer function makes too many threads

Tags: c#, tcplistener

Code:

```
private static TcpListener listener;
static System.Timers.Timer requestReceiver = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
```

in main:

```
listener = new TcpListener(SERVER_IP, serverPort);
listener.Start();
requestReceiver.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ReceiveRequest);
requestReceiver.Enabled = true;
```

now i have function where listener is:

```
private static void ReceiveRequest(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                int requestLength = stream.Read(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
                requestTable = (String[])ByteArrayToObject(requestBytes);

                tcpClient.Close();
             }
         }
         finally
         {
             listener.Stop();
         }
}
```

This code create a lot of threads. Probably this is why it crash after some time. What can I do to avoid thread creation? How to pause listening process? And why this code create so many threads?

Comment: Why is that a timer in the first place? You already have an endless loop, isn't one endless loop enough to handle connections?

Comment: It creates many threads because you told it to create many threads.  What else would you expect a timer to do?

Comment: Can I somehow close threads created by Timer?

Comment: Can we know the reason why you need to use a timer to receive connections?

Comment: In application I need 2 threads, 1st listen, 2nd send. How can I do this? I wanted to receive and send in Timer every 0.1 sec

Comment: Do you mean you need to send data every 0.1 second?

Comment: Yes, i want listen whole time and send every 0.1

Comment: From the code I think the logic you do in the ReceiveRequest method is not very complicated, and it won't take more than 0.1 seconds to process, would you try removing the requestReceiver timer and see if the situation improves?

Comment: In main I use `ReceiveRequest()` function. I changed its body to:

    `private static void ReceiveRequest()`
    `{`            `try`
            `{`
                `while (true)`
                `{`
                    `UpdateGames();`...
and it is receiving and sending properly. When server works alone, I dont see new threads created. Now i have client that listen to. How should I resolve client listening (as I see it creates threads too, it is also using Timer)?

Comment: Can you show us the "send data" code?

Comment: Back to my first problem, I can't insert UpdateGames() into Receive, because Update will work only if Receiver get connection.

Should I move this discussion to chat or something? I dont know how to insert here more code.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to chat..maybe edit the question??

Comment: I will try to move Receive and Send to two normal threads. I think that nobody listen this except you, maybe I can send you PM after I will check Threads?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086900/creating-client-server-application

I changed whole code of this.